# Vega-lite timeseries chart that overlays current, last year and average in a cyclical way

Tags: plot, time-series, vega-lite, vega

I have a simple timeseries with a price over time: `[{t:"2023-01-31", price: 100}, ...]`.

With [vega-lite.js](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) I can easily plot this as a line.

[image]

The script for that is [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQyAE4BrNKEwBPHHDQhhs-QF8lcWVDYATGrLKaQAD0cAzGnEHWDmRSB16Pog4bCpIgn6YdIL66L5mINpuHl4GOCo0UPpKAbEgAI4MSLJRmEhRpJHReemZpjlsbIJROGgA2qDunt5xkbp5mMGh4VWYMT4gZp0pPSC1WX2B6IXFpeU0lTnVaRkLJgC6CaXj6AAKu3AABDiCbJiX1ohsftblKKigxOEMcBDtWgYAEwABkBAEZ+MCAGyQsEAFWBwNQiORwL881iYkRU38QOBYMB-AJsIRSJRiPRFzQYIAzMCcb50CDiaCSeSyWilBjqWIaQy8SDIWI2RzUZS6mgACzYhQApn44XAgAcItRYq5VNQYIA7PTZbj5WDFRD8aS1RSNRKtdL+YbJUSTfD2eq5praXq5SAQcCAJyQlWm50W11WsFgj0Gr34wnAmmq9nihZaum2qNgv1h+McxOxaURxlp7WQv2B0XB7lapX5vG+onArMuiuAkGp5n24FF0vmzkhpNgyVQ1sKyFxrsJy19qHVw0xmFj7MT2JgqdDsEB41m8e92LN6dpmGZ+eNt0+sSrjP1o-lzV51cmmNOss9ivuofgkcN69WrF75klh+bgu25oDSOqUGe+oFsyMYlo+3Y5tSNqQXia7+p+z6aoCWKrsKh5wVuL5KoOyGGpeG5BhhoYtiRaaXgBFEIcmv74pesGAceobYTRzJFuG6GMWuzGofi-GLmg3pvnRonAagt7caCl6dvhQEVjS2oQZ6zIBnOykcUmgI0oC4HnpC7a6V+SaGUZGmRm2kL0U+AkpvJy6wtJL6SnyLklkp7EWbmMqafi9osuZlF9jSNlQYiJbkY5YlauGkkfle4WxDSzlBemxbuTegW2fio4OfBCW0lFNYZsVBFulxWWdr5DGlaeyV8aljFyVlB6XmFjEguVhqKg18UyYJq4BqOPUJRJLkxnFJUjVC-VpnGrWTSNkWroSq1+Wl1KZQVrkdrlnFCSaAZrU2+XRdlsbHZZ1F1WhbWlVWq6jjpO1OUtzKKnN1WcV5QWCrWz0yQOQnth9jUjUhWUmlDw0ed9+IqqFn0JXSzHvqyoMVpKtUHZ2E3ozJ4JCYqZkky+Pr0ocJhAA).

But, I'd like to show such data by month with 3 lines.

- One line shows the data of last year.
- One line showing last year
- One with the average price of the last 5 years.

Something like this:

[image]

This allows a more compact and intuitive reading in some cases. The months wrap around, so the x-axis always has the same size. Comparing the current, with past situations is easier, because the lines are overlaid.

I have tried to

- create additional columns with `transform`, to distinguish those three
- use `{"timeUnit": "month"}`, `{"aggregate": "mean"}` options to reorganize my axis
  ... but without success.

What is the right way to go about this in an elegant Vega-way?

Comment: You're asking for current year, last year and average of last 5 years?

Comment: @DavidBacci, Yes, 3 series, on top of each other. All coming from a plain (t, price) series, covering multiple years of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 600,
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "month",
      "axis": {"labelExpr": "monthAbbrevFormat(datum.value)", "labelAngle": 0}
    },
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "t", "type": "temporal", "title": "t"},
      {"field": "p", "type": "quantitative", "title": "price"}
    ],
    "color": {
      "field": "null",
      "title": "series",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["2021", "2022", "Ave 2016-2021"],
        "range": ["red", "orange", "blueviolet"]
      },
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "stroke": "red"},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.year ==2021"}]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "stroke": "orange"},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.year ==2020"}]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "stroke": "blueviolet", "interpolate": "basis"},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.year <= 2021 && datum.year >= 2016"},
        {
          "aggregate": [{"op": "mean", "field": "price", "as": "price"}],
          "groupby": ["month"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"t": "2021-06-01T00:00:00", "price": 500},
      {"t": "2012-12-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2012-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 153},
      {"t": "2020-05-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2015-08-01T00:00:00", "price": 170},
      {"t": "2015-01-01T00:00:00", "price": 140},
      {"t": "2014-11-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2009-08-01T00:00:00", "price": 110},
      {"t": "2012-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2019-11-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2017-09-01T00:00:00", "price": 180},
      {"t": "2009-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 220},
      {"t": "2014-07-01T00:00:00", "price": 146},
      {"t": "2015-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 160},
      {"t": "2012-06-01T00:00:00", "price": 160},
      {"t": "2018-05-01T00:00:00", "price": 220},
      {"t": "2016-11-01T00:00:00", "price": 195},
      {"t": "2019-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2011-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2021-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 500},
      {"t": "2019-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 317.5},
      {"t": "2012-09-01T00:00:00", "price": 140},
      {"t": "2018-08-01T00:00:00", "price": 250},
      {"t": "2015-11-01T00:00:00", "price": 186},
      {"t": "2010-05-01T00:00:00", "price": 120},
      {"t": "2010-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2010-09-01T00:00:00", "price": 150},
      {"t": "2017-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 180},
      {"t": "2018-01-01T00:00:00", "price": 200},
      {"t": "2020-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2020-07-01T00:00:00", "price": 375},
      {"t": "2018-06-01T00:00:00", "price": 232.5},
      {"t": "2019-04-01T00:00:00", "price": 322.5},
      {"t": "2014-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2016-01-01T00:00:00", "price": 143},
      {"t": "2019-07-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2014-12-01T00:00:00", "price": 135},
      {"t": "2009-05-01T00:00:00", "price": 110},
      {"t": "2020-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 330},
      {"t": "2019-09-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2013-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 135},
      {"t": "2009-12-01T00:00:00", "price": 150},
      {"t": "2017-07-01T00:00:00", "price": 195},
      {"t": "2020-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 400},
      {"t": "2016-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 205},
      {"t": "2015-07-01T00:00:00", "price": 180},
      {"t": "2018-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 200},
      {"t": "2012-05-01T00:00:00", "price": 165},
      {"t": "2013-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 135},
      {"t": "2012-10-01T00:00:00", "price": 130},
      {"t": "2016-07-01T00:00:00", "price": 150},
      {"t": "2011-08-01T00:00:00", "price": 200},
      {"t": "2019-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 320},
      {"t": "2017-08-01T00:00:00", "price": 180},
      {"t": "2013-06-01T00:00:00", "price": 135},
      {"t": "2015-05-01T00:00:00", "price": 153},
      {"t": "2020-09-01T00:00:00", "price": 460},
      {"t": "2014-06-01T00:00:00", "price": 140},
      {"t": "2011-06-01T00:00:00", "price": 145},
      {"t": "2018-12-01T00:00:00", "price": 300},
      {"t": "2021-02-01T00:00:00", "price": 450},
      {"t": "2017-03-01T00:00:00", "price": 210},
      {"t": "2015-04-01T00:00:00", "price": 190}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "year(datum.t)", "as": "year"},
    {"calculate": "month(datum.t)", "as": "month"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David! That's a very concise way of achieving it!